# API request failing due to a 401

Tags: python, urllib

I'm trying to learn how to use APIs which I figured I'd do by using it to improve my experience when playing a game. What I want to do is start out by getting my stats from an API, which I use the following code for:

```
import ssl
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

key = input("what is your API key?")
req = Request('https://public-api.tracker.gg/apex/v1/standard/profile/1/daanenjasper')
#line below added to avoid error 403
req.add_header('User-agent', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8')
req.add_header('apikey', key)
content = urlopen(req).read()

print(content)
```

This will lead to the following output, out of which I only was really able to decifer `http error 401` which doesn't help that much.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/daankoning/Documents/projects/apex/main.py", line 11, in <module>
    content = urlopen(req).read()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

So I'm not really sure what is going wrong here, any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: I'd suggest you try using the requests package...it's a lot easier to use than either urllib version.

Comment: A lot here depends on the format that the API you're calling is expecting the API key, it may simply be expecting the API key to be Base64 encoded, or your header could be wrong; try something like `'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(apikey)` or `'Authorization': 'Basic {}'.format(apikey)`. I agree with Chris though that if you're just trying to learn the basics use the `requests` module if at all possible, it's an industry standard (you almost never see urllib unless you can't use external libs for some reason) and is easier to reason about, more user friendly, etc.